# Django TypeError at / render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'

Tags: python, django, azure, django-views

Currently setting up a Django web application on Azure, deployed through Git locally. I haven't actually written any code yet, and when I start up the development server using

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

and go to the site's address I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /
render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'
```

It's traced to views.py, which has the following contents:

```
"""
Definition of views.
"""

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.template import RequestContext
from datetime import datetime

def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'Home Page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
    )

def contact(request):
    """Renders the contact page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/contact.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'Contact',
            'message':'Your contact page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
    )

def about(request):
    """Renders the about page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/about.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'About',
            'message':'Your application description page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
    )
```

I'm not sure what the error is, since the code was generated when the app was created in Azure. As far as I can tell from the documentation the parameters to render() are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`django.shortcuts.render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)'s third parameter is `context`, not `context_instance`; You should replace `context_instance=` with `context=` (or you can pass it as a positional argument). In addition to that, just pass a dictionary.

```
return render(
    request,
    'app/index.html',
    {
        'title':'Home Page',
        'year':datetime.now().year,
    }
)
```